# In DevOps what is the difference between an artifact and a package

Tags: package, devops, artifactory, artifact

I'm evaluating Jfrog Artifactory, based on their documentation, they use the terms **artifact** and **packages** distinctly. I found some [information on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_repository#Artifacts_and_packages), but i'm still not able to fully understand the difference between an artifact and a package

I come from a .net stack. So when I prepare my application to be deploy my build generates .dll but also can generate nuget packages .nupkg file, that said, is the nuget package an artifact or a package? is it both?

Answer (score 0):

I believe package is going to be the package name in the Java file, like:

```
package com.mycompany.awesomestuff;

public class ouijiball {

}
```

So ouijiball is the artifact in the package com.mycompany.awesomestuff, the artifact addressed as com.mycompany.awesomestuff.ouijiball.